# Filter Specific Part of Speech NLTK

Tags: python, filter, nltk, pos-tagger

this must be simple but I'm missing it somehow.  I have the code:

```
import nltk

f=open('...\\t.txt','rU')
raw=f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
print nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
```

which returns for instance:

"[('processes', 'NNS'), ('a', 'DT'), ('sequence', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('words', 'NNS')]

I was wondering how I could just collected solely all 'NN' for example or all 'DT' AND 'IN' instead of every member of the string.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract only the tags you want with a list comprehension, e.g.:

```
>>> tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
>>> dt_tags = [t for t in tags if t[1] == "DT"]
>>> dt_tags
[('a', 'DT')]
```

Comment: perfect, and just duplicate if I want to find DTs and NNS

tags2 = [t for t in nltk.pos_tag(tokens) if t[1] == "NNS"]
tags2

Comment: Yes, you could even make a dictionary with tags for each type: `all_tags = {tag: [t for t in tags if t[1] == tag] for tag in ["DT", "NNS", ...]}`